# Google play service implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play-services

I want to add google play services to my app but i have an error. I created a leaderboard on play console and i added to games-ids.xml app_Id , leaderboard id and package name. I don't know what can i do ?

Code block like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var counter:Int=0
    private var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient? = null
    private var achievementClient: AchievementsClient? = null
    private var leaderboardsClient: LeaderboardsClient? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initGoogleClientAndSignin()

        leaderboardsClient?.submitScore("leader_board_id", counter.toLong())



        button1.setOnClickListener {
            counter += 1
            tvDisplay.text=counter.toString()
        }

    }
    fun initGoogleClientAndSignin() {
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
                GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build())

        googleSignInClient?.silentSignIn()?.addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                achievementClient = Games.getAchievementsClient(this,
                    task.result!!)
                leaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this,
                    task.result!!)
            } else {
                Log.e("Error", "signInError", task.exception)
            }
        }
    }

    fun showAchievements(view: View) {
        achievementClient?.achievementsIntent?.addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
    }

    fun showTopPlayers(view: View) {
        leaderboardsClient?.allLeaderboardsIntent?.addOnSuccessListener {intent ->
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

When i run app no google sign in or when i click the button nothing happen
Also Error this is :

```
  signInError
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 8:
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.zaf(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaj.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zaa(Unknown Source:172)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source:131)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzj.zzc(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzt.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzd.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Comment: You get ApiException 
 8 which says "internal error, trying again might fix it" which sucks as an error msg ;-D https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-internal_error

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of the gradle dependencies? Are you signed in to Google Play Services? Is google Play services app up to date?

Comment: Yes these are up to date           implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0'
 `   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

Comment: @Blundell can you run this codes